# disable bluetooth file transfer on ubuntu host for a specific user

Tags: linux, bluetooth, file-transfer, gnome

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 and I need to keep bluetooth and the applet running as it's required but I want to disable file transferring via bluetooth for a known user or disable it system wide.

I need to be able to disable this via command line or be editing a conf file directly.
This user must not be able to enable this feature.
I'm using gnome environment.

I've looked into dconf and this isn't working due to the configuration management.

I can't uninstall the bluez-obexd package because of dependencies.

Is there a polkit rule I can set that denies file transfers?